# Getting 400 error when using post request in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular4-forms

I've written code to post a request to an endpoint in Angular 4. Here is my code...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component({
templateUrl: "./name.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./name.component.css"]
})

export class nameComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("init");
}

saveForm() {
  let names = [
    {
      name: "Bob"
    }
  ];

JSON.stringify(names);

let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.append("Authorization", `my_token`);

this.http
  .post("endpoint", names, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .subscribe(err => console.log(err));
}
}
```

This is the code I have on the html page that triggers the POST call

```
<button
 type="button"
 (click)="saveForm()"
>
Save
</button>
```

When I go to the page and click the button, I get a 400 (Bad Request) error.

```
message: "Http failure response for endpoint: 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
url: "endpoint"
```

I substituted the word "endpoint" for the real url.

I have no syntax errors, but what could trigger a 400? I tried hitting the endpoint through LoopBack API Explorer and it worked.

I appreciate any help someone can give me!

Comment: 400 is a `Bad Request`. Whatever the endpoint is expecting, it's not getting it.

Comment: The endpoint is expecting an array of objects. That's what I'm passing into the this.http.post call.

Comment: Do you control the endpoint? If not, I'd check the docs.

Comment: Just stringify the object and pass - that might solve the issue most probably

Comment: If you look at the code, I did that with JSON.stringify(names).

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving the output of JSON.stringify() so you're using the object and not a string when you make the POST:

```
names = JSON.stringify(names);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error of "names is a required argument". It's almost like when I hit the url, it doesn't see that I'm passing the object names as a parameter.

It's treating like I sent a null object as part of the POST request.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you inspect the request with the browser developer tools, do you see the names being sent? Does the data match what you sent when you used the LoopBack API explorer and got a success?